# Diffeomorphism problem for complex surfaces?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

I'm sure the following is well known by the right people, I'm just hoping for some pointers.  I know about Markov's theorem that the diffeomorphism problem for general 4-manifolds is undecidable.

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two closed 4-manifolds, say they are given to us with triangulations.  Also say we are given complex structures on $X_1$ and $X_2$ (I am not sure how to specify complex structures with a finite amount of data, however I would imagine that in the moduli space of all complex structures there is a dense subset that can be specified somehow with a finite amount of data).

1. Does there exist an algorithm to determine if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are diffeomorphic (with the unique smooth structures coming from the respective triangulations)?

And just to make my prior parenthetical point part of the question:

2. Is there a way to specify some complex structures on $X_1$ and $X_2$ given that they admit complex structures?

Comment: You should add the assumption that your manifolds are compact (closed).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you, yes absolutely.  Done!

Comment: As for the (modified) question itself, I am pretty sure that the answer is unknown (standard arguments do not work and nobody found anything else besides small variations on the standard proof to show undecidability of the homeomorphism/diffeomorphism problem for 4-manifolds).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you.  Are you aware of any reasonable sized classes of 4-manifolds where the diffeomorphism problem is decidable? Maybe surface bundles over surfaces for example?

Comment: I think that it is undecidable already for bundles since there are finitely generated subgroups of the mapping class group (genus $\ge 2$) which one cannot tell apart algorithmically.

Comment: My comment about bundles was in the smooth category: There are too very few know constructions of bundles which are complex manifolds to say something definitive here. But I do not think the answer is known in this case either.